# Trying to find the first letter in row in SQL

Tags: sql, indexing, char, toad-data-point

I have a dataset that looks at Loans by Branch and I want to find the position of the first string character by row and returning the position it is in, Below is an example of what I am looking at:

```
Loan #       Loan Substring 
---------------------------
1234BL           5
123BL            4
12SBL            3
```

I tried `CHARINDEX`, but I want to look at multiple substrings instead of one - any suggestions?

Comment: What I want is to return the position of the first letter to show in a separate column [New_column].

Comment: Could you try this - `PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', [Loan Substring])`?

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression would do the job, but the syntax is not standard. Which is your DBMS ?

In Oracle this would be something like `SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(Loan, '[A-Z]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', [Loan Substring])
```